# blog objects need to have a primary key value before you can access their tags

Tags: python, django

i am trying to create a blog by the admin panell.  but i am not able to save.  Can you please help.
Model.py

```
class blog(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    city_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    blog_title=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    tags = TaggableManager()
    blog_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    blog_sub_category_name=models.ForeignKey(blog_sub_category,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,blank=True)
    written_by = models.CharField(max_length=200, default='sandeep')
    image_banner= models.ImageField(upload_to='image_banner')
    medium_thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='medium_thumbnail')
    content = RichTextField() # RichTextField is used for paragraphs
    is_authentic=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    class Meta: # Plurizing the class name explicitly
        verbose_name_plural = 'blog'
     
    def __str__(self): # Dundar Method
        return self.blog_title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs): # Saving Modefied Changes
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.blog_title)
```

view.py

```
def tags(request,tags):
    blogs = blog.objects.filter(
            Q(blog_title__icontains = tags.replace('-',' ')) |
            Q(content__icontains = tags.replace('-',' '))
        )
    print(tags)
    return render(request, 'services/blog-with-sidebar.html',
        {'blogs': blogs,'media_url':settings.MEDIA_URL})
```

For some reason when I'm trying to save the tags and the data I'm getting this error:

Comment: Please add your code to your question as formatted text not as images

Comment: Please review How to Ask https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the problem. You have not included enough detail in your question for anyone to help you